# ORACLE Использование SERIALIZABLE в PL/SQL для выгрузки согласованного набора данных

Tags: oracle, serializable, execute

Стоит задача выгрузить в стейжинг слой согласованный набор данных из заданного списка таблиц. Таблицы вс стейжинге всегда чистые, созданы с нуля. Выгрузку делает процедура:

```
   procedure move_tables_to_mst_layer(v_sync sync_data) is
   pragma autonomous_transaction;
   v_src_table  varchar2(128);
   sql_stm      varchar2(30000);
   v_proc    varchar2(128);

begin

   execute immediate 'alter session SET ISOLATION_LEVEL = SERIALIZABLE';

   for rec in (select a_tbl_name as tblnm from a_tables
                where a_tbl_type in ('T0', 'T1')
                order by a_tbl_order
              )
   loop

       v_src_table := 'STG_'||rec.tblnm;
       sql_stm := 'insert /*+ append */ into '||v_src_table||' select t1.*
                    from '||rec.tblnm||' t1
                   where row_seq > '||v_sync.v_rowseq
                     ;
       --dbms_output.put_line(sql_stm);
       execute immediate sql_stm;
       --commit;
   end loop;

   commit;
   execute immediate 'alter session SET ISOLATION_LEVEL = READ COMMITTED';
exception
when others then
    errpck.raise_n_stop('SYNC', v_proc, 'Procedure move_tables_to_mst_layer');
end move_tables_to_mst_layer;
```

Данные под OLTP нагрузкой. Индикаторное поле row_seq - управляется триггером, при каждой операции изменения данных, в поле кладется следующее значение из сиквенса.
И не работает. На пилотных продуктивных схемах через 6-12 часов регулярно ловится ошибка по рассинхрону - захватили дочерние записи, но пропустили родительские. Чтобы избежать ошибок унаследованных от прошлых попыток, перед каждым запускаем инсерчу отсутствующие записи из базы-родителя в целевую базу по примари-кей, минуя стейжинговый слой.
Подозреваю, что неправильно использую оператор execute immediate - это новый плскл блок, который исключается из сериалайз режима. Настройки базы смотреть/менять не могу - прав нет.
Что еще? Перед вызовом процедуры move_tables_to_mst_layer делаю commit; - уже и commit work; пробовал делать, хоть это и то же самое.
Версия Oracle 12c.
Есть сущестувующий функционал выгрузки, напилен на жава, и отправляет пакеты с данными таблиц в целевую базу, данные получает в transaction read only - вот он работает стабильно.
Но теперь требуется передавать через стейжинг.

Comment: Так а что не получается? Привидите пожалуйста  [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @0xdb Это OLTP - если бы я знал, в какой момент не получается, то привел бы минимальный. Но схема такая
исходная база -> копируем в стейжинг ареа -> копируем в целевую базу.
Периодически валимся по форин-кей - отсутствие записи в родительской таблице. Не могу придумать сценарий, чтобы захватились записи из дочерней таблицы, и не захватились из родительской.

Comment: Пока не совсем понятно. Вы пытаетесь копировать записи из одной таблицы в неё же.  Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: @0xdb сорри, при уборке кода от "лишних" переменных слегка поторопился. Поправил значение v_src_table

Comment: Поэтому и просил привести минимальный рабочий пример. Что находится в таблице  a_tables, и что значит  'T0', 'T1' нельзя в вопросе указать? Если вы читаете инконсистентные данные, то тут два варианта: 1) не читать их 2) посмотреть, откуда они берутся и устранить ошибку. Так в чём ваш вопрос?

Comment: Пока ответ на часть вопроса:  `execute immediate`  это не новый PL/SQL блок, запрос в нём будет выполнен в той же транзакции, и с тем же уровнем изоляции как и транзакция в целом. Небольшое уточнение: почему вы пользуйтесь `alter session ...`, а не `set transaction ...`?

Comment: @0xdb В a_tables список таблиц из которых выгружаем данные. Исходные таблицы неконсистентных данных не содержат (в них те же форин кеи, что и в целевой базе), нарушения ссылочной целостности появляются именно во время копирования. Alter session носит более глобальный характер, раньше был set transaction, но стал ловить несогласованную выгрузку и переделал на session.

Comment: 1) _Alter session носит более глобальный_, что вы под этим понимаете? У вас сейчас одна транзакция.  _в них те же форин кеи, что и в целевой базе_, как это понять? Вы же жалуетесь, что вторичные ключи не записываются, потому что первичный ключ потерялся (или я не правильно понял - _валимся по форин-кей_). 3) Ещё уточнение, раз вы запускаете в `autonomous_transaction`, значит из уже открытой транзакции. Если так, то что она делает?

Comment: Извините конечно, но вы дали полурабочий код, без структуры таблиц, без данных. То есть, просите найти ошибку тех, кто сидя перед "чёрным ящиком" пытается угадать его содержимое. Какой ответ вы ожидаете на ваш вопрос? Впрочем, сам вопрос трудно распознаваем, т.к. вопросительный знак в тексте только один. На него я уже ответил в комментарии.